# Android Studio importing Jetbrains Exposed

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to Android development.  I have created a new project with Android Studio and need to import jetbrains exposed library into my existing project.  When I tried to follow the exposed Getting Started guide to add the following into the build.grade file:

```
repositories {
  maven {
    url  "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/exposed" 
  }
}
dependencies {
  compile 'org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed:0.10.2'
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Could not find method compile() for arguments [org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed:0.10.2] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

I have been searching the internet for a couple of days now but still could not find out what's the problem.

This is the build.gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.40'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url  "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/exposed"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed:0.10.2'
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Hopefully someone could help me.

Thanking in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put this dependency in the module level `build.gradle` file - by default, this is in the `app` folder, as opposed to the project level `build.gradle` file, which is in the root of your project.

Also, you should use `implementation` instead of `compile`, since you're using a newer than 3.0 version of the Android Gradle plugin:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url  "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/exposed"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed:0.10.2'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  After I moved the code as suggested to app folder build.gradle file and try to add Database.connect(jdbc:h2:mem:test", driver = "org.h2.Driver") into my project, I am getting 10 errors: eg, Unexpected type specification, expecting ')', expecting an element, unresolved reference:jdbc and etc.  Do you have any idea what would be the root caused?

Comment: I think you should post any issues related to actually using the library as separate questions, as they are no longer related to this question about the Gradle dependencies..